# getting null response with http post with multiple parameters

Tags: http-post, angular2-services, typescript2.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using http post request with 2 parameters and getting null response from service.
Below is code snippet from my angular service and also the controller (C#).

I tried two options but none of them are working and getting null response in both cases.

looks like parameters are not passed from service and thus proper routing is not matching... as I tried debugging the controller... I do not see the debugger hitting the method in controller... any clue as what I am doing wrong ? or is there any other approach I can follow ?

```
   Option 1     let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('id',bookId);
        params.append('store',store);

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let body = JSON.stringify(params);

        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, body, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())  
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); 


Option 2
        let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');    
        let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('id',bookId);
        params.append('store',store);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, params: myParams });

        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())  
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));   


controller code
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/book/{id}/{store}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetByIdPwd(string id, string store)
        {
            var book = bookRepo.GetBookAvailabilityBy(id, store);
            return Ok(book);

        }
```